# Automatic Programatic CGRect frame for iPhone 5 like Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, frame, autosize, autoresizingmask

I was wondering if there was any way to automatically and programmatically generate frames for different size screens like they are done in storyboard. In storyboard, as long as the autosizing mask is set correctly, the frames for the views are generated dynamically to fill the entire screen. This can be shown when the 'Apply *Alternate Device* Form Factor' button in storyboard is pressed and the screen size & content grow or shrink dynamically.  However, whenever I try to get this same behavior while creating views programmatically,  the frame does not scale dynamically. Is there any way to generate this frame automatically like Storyboard based on the current devices framework? Is there any elegant solution to programmatically create views for different size devices without needing to manually manage static frames for each devices? Does anyone have any resources they could share or examples that they could provide?

Thanks. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the frame statically you should place the frame based on the size (height for example) from areas. For instance this would create the view and place it 50 from the bottom and also stretch the size if the devices height was 568 instead of 480).

```
someView.frame = CGRectMake (0,someView.frame.size.height + (self.view.frame.size.height - 50),100 + (480 - self.view.frame.height),100);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS6 you can use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html).  If you're not targeting iOS6 (or you don't want to mess with Auto Layout) you can set UIView's autoResizingMask property to whatever you want. i.e. `view.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am currently setting the view's autoresizing mask programmatically but this does not change the view's position on the screen when it is first drawn. This only affects the view's frame whenever its parent's bounds change, like when the device is rotated.

Comment: If you're adding the view after the view controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews OR the superview is already configured for the larger screen you will have to adjust the view's frame.  If the view controller is designed in IB at 3.5" and you add the view in viewDidLoad while setting the autoResizingMask it will automatically lay it out.

You can also add the view during viewWillLayoutSubviews and calculate the height of the view controller's view to make your adjustments.